# AWS Redis session provider exception- No connection is available to service this operation: EVAL

Tags: session-state, redis

I'm trying with Sitecore 8.2 and Sitecore 9.0.2 to change the session state provider from inproc to AWS hosted Redis session provider and get the following exception:

> [RedisConnectionException: No connection is available to service this operation: EVAL]
>      StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl(Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) +690
>      StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync(Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) +122
>      StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ScriptEvaluate(String script, RedisKey[] keys, RedisValue[] values, CommandFlags flags) +141
>      Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.b__0() +55
>      Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.RetryForScriptNotFound(Func`1 redisOperation) +140
>      Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.RetryLogic(Func`1 redisOperation) +144
>      Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.Eval(String script, String[] keyArgs, Object[] valueArgs) +609
>      Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisConnectionWrapper.TryTakeWriteLockAndGetData(String sessionId, DateTime lockTime, Object& lockId, ISessionStateItemCollection& data, Int32& sessionTimeout) +352
>      Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider.GetItemFromSessionStore(Boolean isWriteLockRequired, HttpContext context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actions) +1113
>      Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider.GetItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actions) +225
>      System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.GetSessionStateItem() +169
>      System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +1002
>      System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +689
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +213
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +131

This is what I changed in my web.config (Sitecore 8.2):

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="redis" timeout="20">
    <providers>
        <add name="redis" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider,Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis" connectionString="session" pollingInterval="2" applicationName="private"/>         
    </providers>
</sessionState>
```

This is the AWS Redis endpoint defined in my connectionString.config (Sitecore 8.2)

```
<add name="session" connectionString="example.cache.amazonaws.com:6000,password=xxxx,ssl=true,abortConnect=False" />
```

I am doubting that StackExchange.Redis version used by Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis is 1.0.488 and this maybe the cause of the issue.

I wonder if anyone else has come across a similar exception using Redis provider on AWS. Appreciate any pointers to troubleshoot the issue.

UPDATED: Sitecore logs showing connection to Redis

> 33488 15:15:31 INFO  All tasks are already complete
>   33488 15:15:31 INFO  example.cache.amazonaws.com:6000 failed to nominate (Faulted)
>   33488 15:15:31 INFO  > UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on GET
>   33488 15:15:31 INFO  No masters detected
>   33488 15:15:31 INFO  example.cache.amazonaws.com:6000 Cluster v4.0.10, slave; keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: Connecting; sub: ConnectedEstablished, 1 active; not in use: DidNotRespond
>   33488 15:15:31 INFO  example.cache.amazonaws.com:6000: int ops=8, qu=0, qs=0, qc=2, wr=0, sync=9, socks=2; sub ops=4, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, subs=1, sync=4, socks=1
>   33488 15:15:31 INFO  Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0+8=8 (0.80 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0+4=4 (0.40 ops/s; spans 10s)
>   33488 15:15:31 INFO  Sync timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
>   33488 15:15:31 INFO  resetting failing connections to retry...
>   33488 15:15:31 INFO  retrying; attempts left: 2...
>   33488 15:15:31 INFO  1 unique nodes specified
>   33488 15:15:31 INFO  Requesting tie-break from example.cache.amazonaws.com:6000 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
>   33488 15:15:31 INFO  Allowing endpoints 00:00:05 to respond...
>   33488 15:15:31 INFO  Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=4,Free=32763,Min=4,Max=32767)
>   33488 15:15:31 INFO  All tasks completed cleanly, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=3,Free=32764,Min=4,Max=32767)
>   33488 15:15:31 INFO  example.cache.amazonaws.com:6000 returned, but incorrectly
>   33488 15:15:31 INFO  Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=3,Free=32764,Min=4,Max=32767)
>   29412 15:15:31 INFO  Not all tasks completed cleanly, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=32765,Min=4,Max=32767)
>   29412 15:15:31 INFO  example.cache.amazonaws.com:6000 failed to nominate (WaitingForActivation)
>   29412 15:15:31 INFO  No masters detected

Comment: We have this working but there can be many reasons for this to happen. Do you see any connections when you look at Redis in AWS console? When Sitecore starts it will ping Redis, what is the result of this in this Sitecore log?

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen for your response. I am yet to see the AWS console but on Sitecore logs I see it gets authenticated and connected but after that it tries to ping where it says No Master detected. I have updated my Post with sitecore logs

Comment: One thing you could try is to change the Redis engine version from v4.0.10 to 3.2.6, this is what we are using and is closest to version 3.2.7 which is used by Azure's Redis engine.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen, downgrading to 3.2.6 version worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you also should change the shared session state as per [Sitecore's documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/session_state/session_state/walkthrough_configuring_a_shared_session_state_database_using_the_redis_provider) as having them different could cause this issue and other issues.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the input but that did not help. I see the same exception and sitecore logs

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore Support responded that their current StackExchange library does not support 4.0.10 version. After downgrading the Redis engine to 3.2.6, we were able to configure Redis session.