# Are there specific configuration requirements for Redis in Azure?

Tags: azure, session-state, redis

We're attempting to configure Azure Redis cache, I'm confident the connection string is correct as the logs suggests it's been able to make a connection. However my knowledge of using Redis with Sitecore is rather low. It looks like the issue is related to `failed to nominate` and `No masters detected`. It feels like we're missing something very obvious here.

```
3400 14:41:33 INFO  <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=<obfuscated>,ssl=True,abortConnect=False
3400 14:41:33 INFO  
3400 14:41:33 INFO  Connecting <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive...
3400 14:41:33 INFO  BeginConnect: <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380
3400 14:41:33 INFO  1 unique nodes specified
3400 14:41:33 INFO  Requesting tie-break from <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
3400 14:41:33 INFO  Allowing endpoints 00:00:05 to respond...
3400 14:41:33 INFO  Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=4,Free=32763,Min=2,Max=32767)
 908 14:41:33 INFO  EndConnect: <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380
 908 14:41:33 INFO  Configuring SSL
1128 14:41:34 INFO  All tasks completed cleanly, IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=6,Free=32761,Min=2,Max=32767)
1128 14:41:34 INFO  <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380 faulted: UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on PING
 908 14:41:34 INFO  Connect complete: <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380
1128 14:41:34 INFO  All tasks are already complete
1128 14:41:34 INFO  <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380 failed to nominate (Faulted)
1128 14:41:34 INFO  > UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on GET
1128 14:41:34 INFO  No masters detected
1128 14:41:34 INFO  <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380: Standalone v2.0.0, master; keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: Connecting; sub: Connecting; not in use: DidNotRespond
1128 14:41:34 INFO  <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380: int ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=1, wr=0, sync=1, socks=2; sub ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=2
1128 14:41:34 INFO  Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s)
1128 14:41:34 INFO  Sync timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
1128 14:41:34 INFO  resetting failing connections to retry...
1128 14:41:34 INFO  retrying; attempts left: 2...
1128 14:41:34 INFO  1 unique nodes specified
1128 14:41:34 INFO  Requesting tie-break from <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
1128 14:41:34 INFO  Allowing endpoints 00:00:05 to respond...
1128 14:41:34 INFO  Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=6,Free=32761,Min=2,Max=32767)
1128 14:41:34 INFO  All tasks completed cleanly, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=6,Free=32761,Min=2,Max=32767)
1128 14:41:34 INFO  <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380 returned, but incorrectly
1128 14:41:34 INFO  Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=6,Free=32761,Min=2,Max=32767)
5252 14:41:34 INFO  Not all tasks completed cleanly, IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=5,Free=32762,Min=2,Max=32767)
5252 14:41:34 INFO  <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380 failed to nominate (WaitingForActivation)
5252 14:41:34 INFO  No masters detected
5252 14:41:34 INFO  <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380: Standalone v2.0.0, master; keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: Connecting; sub: Connecting; not in use: DidNotRespond
5252 14:41:34 INFO  <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380: int ops=0, qu=2, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, sync=1, async=2, socks=3; sub ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=3
5252 14:41:34 INFO  Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s)
5252 14:41:34 INFO  Sync timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
5252 14:41:34 INFO  resetting failing connections to retry...
5252 14:41:34 INFO  retrying; attempts left: 1...
5252 14:41:34 INFO  1 unique nodes specified
5252 14:41:34 INFO  Requesting tie-break from <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
5252 14:41:34 INFO  Allowing endpoints 00:00:05 to respond...
5252 14:41:34 INFO  Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=6,Free=32761,Min=2,Max=32767)
5252 14:41:39 INFO  Not all tasks completed cleanly, IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=5,Free=32762,Min=2,Max=32767)
5252 14:41:39 INFO  <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380 did not respond
5252 14:41:39 INFO  Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=5,Free=32762,Min=2,Max=32767)
1128 14:41:39 INFO  Not all tasks completed cleanly, IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=5,Free=32762,Min=2,Max=32767)
1128 14:41:39 INFO  <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380 failed to nominate (WaitingForActivation)
1128 14:41:39 INFO  No masters detected
1128 14:41:39 INFO  <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380: Standalone v2.0.0, master; keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: Connecting; sub: Connecting; not in use: DidNotRespond
1128 14:41:39 INFO  <obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380: int ops=0, qu=2, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, sync=1, async=5, socks=4; sub ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=4
1128 14:41:39 INFO  Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s)
1128 14:41:39 INFO  Sync timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
```

This question is very similar to [AWS Redis session provider exception- No connection is available to service this operation: EVAL](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14704/aws-redis-session-provider-exception-no-connection-is-available-to-service-this), but in this instance we're using Azure which is running 3.2.7 and no way of selecting a different version.

EDIT: Adding connection string

`<obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,abortConnect=false,ssl=true,password=<obfuscated>`

EDIT 2: Adding Web.config settings I tried

```
<add name="redis"
    type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis"
    applicationName="private"
    host="<obfuscated>.redis.cache.windows.net"
    port="6380"
    accessKey="<obfuscated>"
    ssl="true"
    pollingInterval="2"
    compression="true"
/>
```

Comment: When you look at Redis in the Azure portal do you see any connections? The failed to nominate and No masters detected are just info messages, might just be there because Redis is not running in cluster mode.

Comment: While working on a 9.0.2 install a few weeks ago, had issues with the Azure Redis provider in an On Prem install. It couldn't read the connection string correctly from the ConnectionStrings.config. I ended up having to use the alternate connection string config in the web.config, specifying host, port, and instance.

Comment: @PeteNavarra - I've actually tried doing this as well, added the Redis node I used when trying via the Web.config instead of connection string.

Comment: @Jeroen - I'll take a look this morning and see if any connections are coming in.

Comment: @Jeroen I see 8 connected clients, but from what I understand this is Azure connecting to it for health purposes.